# How to divide Image into 5*5 pieces Windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, writeablebitmap

I am developing an application where i have to divide an image into separate images, i have tried with 
WriteableBitmap , here is my code. Is there any better way to achieve the same?

**XAML**

```
                <Grid Name="gridCollague" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="473" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="446">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition   Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
```

**Code Behind:**

How can i divide the image into 5*5 pieces of equal size

```
    int halfWidth = wb.PixelWidth / 5;
    int halfHeight = wb.PixelHeight / 5;
    WriteableBitmap img1 = wb.Crop(0, 0, halfWidth, halfHeight);
    WriteableBitmap img2 = wb.Crop(halfWidth, 0, halfWidth, halfHeight);
    WriteableBitmap img3 = wb.Crop(0, halfHeight, halfWidth, halfHeight);
    WriteableBitmap img4 = wb.Crop(halfWidth, halfHeight, halfWidth, halfHeight);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to check the [DeepZoom](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/03/28/deep-zoom-on-wp7.aspx)

> The [Deep Zoom (Seadragon)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645050(VS.95).aspx) functionality has been available on
>   Silverlight since version 2. It's a techonology that provides the
>   ability to interactively view high-resolution images. The images need
>   to be prepared using available tools like [Deep Zoom Composer and
>   others](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901589(v=VS.95).aspx). The functionality is provided via the usage of the
>   MultiScaleImage control which is availabe on WP7. This control is not
>   there by default in your Toolbox in Visual Studio, however you can
>   just right-click on the Toolbox, select "Choose item..." menu and pick
>   the control from the list

Comment: Thanks,could you provide a sample which fulfill my requirement

Comment: @Sajeetharan:- Did you check this: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/113492/Splitting-an-image-in-n-x-m-images